# How to check whether CLOB is null or not in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I created table that has one CLOB.

And I am developing web site with Spring framework and Ibatis.

and I try to do select Query like `select CLOB_COL from table`.

but Ibatis shows NPE.

I guess this problem is from returning null from CLOB column.

this error is shown only when CLOB column is null.

How can I check CLOB is null or not in Query?

And tips is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: `CLOB_COL IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I try to do that. But I need to get "" if clob_col is null.

Comment: If I use "CLOB_COL" is not null on where, clob_col that is null is not selected.

Comment: Perhaps this: `NVL(CLOB_COL, EMPTY_CLOB)`

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! it works very well. Thanks!